# Solving electrostatics Poisson equation with Intel MKL routines

Tags: poisson, electromagnetism, intel-mkl

I am trying to solve  the 3D Poisson equation

$$\nabla\cdot(\epsilon(\mathbf{r})\nabla) u(\mathbf{r}) = f(\mathbf{r})$$

I notice intel advertises [routines](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-fast-poisson-solver-routines) that appear to solve

$$\nabla^2u(\mathbf{r}) = f(\mathbf{r})$$

Does anyone know if I can find similar such routines for solving the more general electrostatics Poisson equation above?

Comment: ...are you looking for such routines/routine sequencies only within Intel MKL?

Comment: The FFT approach used to solve $\nabla^{2} u = f$ isn't applicable to the more general equation.

Comment: @AntonMenshov Intel MKL would be ideal, as opposed to, say, my own jacobi solver. I've found a routine "pardiso" that may be useful.